# Problemas con lastInsertId()

Tags: php, pdo

En una instalación Windows Server 2008, base de datos PostgreSQL, tengo el siguiente trozo de código en PHP:

```
$this->con->beginTransaction();
try {
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare(
        'INSERT INTO sedoc.proc_dest(id_categoria, ci)'     
        . ' VALUES (:categoria, :ci)'
    );
    $stmt->bindValue(':ci', trim($procdestModel->getCI())); 
    $stmt->bindValue(':categoria', $categoria);
    $stmt->execute();
    $ultimo = $this->con->lastInsertId('proc_dest_id_proc_dest_seq');
    this->con->commit();
    return $ultimo;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $this->con->rollBack();
    Message::setMessage('registro', 'Error!', 'error');
    return false;
}
```

Inserta con éxito el registro en la tabla, pero `lastInsertId` no devuelve nada. El asunto es que necesito ese valor para continuar trabajando con él.
El nombre de la secuencia es correcto ... Está ANTES del commit ... si quito la transacción, continúa con el mismo comportamiento.
¿Alguna idea de qué es lo que está sucediendo?

Comment: La petición de la ID parece correcta, haz un var_dump() de **$ultimo** antes y después del commit() a ver que pasa.

Comment: @A.Cedano el parámetro que recibe `lastInsertId` es el nombre de la secuencia que automáticamente se crea al tener un campo serial en Postgres

Comment: @Dev.Joel Sí, al leer _Windows Server 2008, base de datos PostgreSQL_ me confundí y creí que usaba una BD SQL Server. Borraré el comentario. Gracias.

Comment: _Este método puede no devolver resultados significativos o consistentes para diferentes drivers PDO, debido a que la base de datos subyacente puede no soportar el concepto de campos auto-incrementales o secuencias._ ¿La tabla tiene un campo auto-incremental? ¿La secuencia de autoincremento estás seguro que se llama así?

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que `lastInsertId` funciona para MySQL pero no para Postgres, aunque está documentado que pasándole el nombre de la secuencia sí funciona. ¿Será que no funciona en transacciones? No podría decirlo.

Lo que sí puedo decir es que Postgres tiene la cláusula `RETURNING`. Si tu autoincremental se llama `proc_dest_id`, entonces sería:

```
$this->con->beginTransaction();

$stmt = $this->con->prepare(
    'INSERT INTO sedoc.proc_dest(id_categoria, ci)'     
    . ' VALUES (:categoria, :ci)'
    . ' RETURNING proc_dest_id'
);
$stmt->bindValue(':ci', trim($procdestModel->getCI())); 
$stmt->bindValue(':categoria', $categoria);
$stmt->execute();
$this->con->commit();
$ultimo = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

¿Cómo puede ser eso de usar fetch después de un INSERT? Bueno, es porque el insert está retornando algo, así que puedes leer el resultado en vez de simplemente comprobar que se haya realizado exitosamente.

Comment: Si este se confirma: +1. Parece muy interesante y curioso. La doc de PDO en PHP y en Microsoft son incompatibles. Leí en la explicación de Microsoft que para obtener el last insert en vez del nombre de la secuencia, había que pasarle el nombre de la tabla, mientras que en postgresql hay que pasarle el nombre de la secuencia. Y un comentario de PHP dice: _It should be mentioned that this function DOES NOT retrieve the ID (Primary key) of the row but it's OID instead._ En fin, un lío. :)